# Is using 1 instead of true in a docs file valid?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to parse a docx file generated by Google doc. I am looking at a XWPFRun element called run. If I call run.isBold() it returns false, even when the element is bold. If I look at run.getCTR() I get the xml below. As you can see it says

```
<w:b w:val="1"/>
```

instead of

```
<w:b w:val="true"/>
```

and this causes isBold() to return false(I guess). If I import the file in LibreOffice, and exports it again isBold() is returning true, so is this a bug in google doc export, or poi? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
<xml-fragment w:rsidDel="00000000" w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRPr="00000000" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:lc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Verdana" w:cs="Verdana" w:eastAsia="Verdana" w:hAnsi="Verdana"/>
    <w:b w:val="1"/>
    <w:sz w:val="36"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
    <w:rtl w:val="0"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">Kapitel 1: Digitale tømmermænd</w:t>
  <w:br w:type="textWrapping"/>
</xml-fragment>
```

Comment: You can look up the acceptable values in the respective schema (comes with POI) or the Standard (ECMA 376 / ISO 29500 - Google is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

From wml.xsd in POI ooxml-lib/OpenOfficeXML-XMLSchemas.zip, I would conclude that 1|true|on are all acceptable and equivalent True values, and 0|false|off are all acceptable and equivalent False values. Any application should be able to write any of these 6 values of its choosing to the XML file and any application should be able to read any of these 6 values with 100% intelligibility.

You have found a bug in POI. Looking at the [implementation](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.java?revision=1734182&view=markup#l237) of isBold (and isItalic and anything else using isCTOnOff), the code is ignoring the "1"/"0" case you discovered. The code should also use STOnOff.X_1.

This is now [fixed on POI trunk](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59208) and will be available in the next POI release (3.15 beta 1).

```
<xsd:element name="b" type="CT_OnOff" minOccurs="0">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Bold</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="CT_OnOff">
  <xsd:attribute name="val" type="ST_OnOff">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>On/Off Value</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="ST_OnOff">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>On/Off Value</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="true">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>True</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="false">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>False</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="on">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>True</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="off">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>False</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="0">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>False</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:enumeration>
    <xsd:enumeration value="1">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>True</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:enumeration>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```